# Data Analytics with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to integrate my Neo4j graph database on Rails app with [GraphLab](http://graphlab.com/) for `data analytics`. Is it possible to integrate GraphLab directly without explicitly taking out the database snapshots?

Are there any other tools that can be easily integrated with Neo4j for the same?

If not possible, then the concern is that Neo4j doesn't allow to export data in csv format. While GraphLab only allows csv imports.

Comment: You could use py2neo to query the db and write the contents to csv using Python's writecsv. Also the browser allows you to save query results as csv.

Comment: Thanks @NicoleWhite, I just visited py2neo but it doesn't offer any machine learning techniques like Clustering, collaborative filtering etc which GraphLab does. Using py2neo specifically for exporting complete database to csv and then to do analysis at GraphLab will not be scalable at production. (Please, correct me if I am wrong) Any other way to do machine learning related data analytics with neo4j?

Comment: Have you considered igraph?

Comment: Thanks, I am exploring it now

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is small enough to fit into RAM, you could do this import in a few steps:

1. Use [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-export) to export from neo4j to GraphML.
2. Use [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.read_graphml.html) to import from GraphML to a NetworkX Graph object (let's call it `g`).
3. Use a loop or list comprehension to add the vertices and edges from the NetworkX graph to a [`graphlab.SGraph`](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SGraph.html) (let's call it `sg`):

`import graphlab
sg = graphlab.SGraph()
sg = sg.add_vertices([graphlab.Vertex(i) for i in g.nodes()])
sg = sg.add_edges([graphlab.Edge(*edge) for edge in g.edges()])`

You could also use py2neo (as described in the comments above to query the graph) but instead of writing to CSV, directly build the `SGraph` from the queries, either using add_vertices and add_edges, or by building vertex/edge SFrames and then using those to construct the graph. This might be a faster solution for production (with no intermediate disk representation) and may also help get around the memory size limitation if your graph is larger than will fit in RAM.

Comment: Unfortunately the database is huge(which won't fit on RAM)

Comment: @red-devil In that case you might be able to directly read into SGraph using py2neo and add_vertices/add_edges. SGraph will be able to handle arbitrary large graphs (it is disk-backed).